# How to force queryset to be evaluated so that exception can be caught in the view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have an `OperationalError` exception thrown during view rendering.

So I tried to catch it before the rendering in `views.py`

```
try:
    dossiersdb = Person.objects.using('dbn').all()
    print(dossiersdb)
except OperationalError as exp :
    logger.warning("Got %s", exp) 
    return HttpResponse('<h1>OperationalError</h1>')
```

But I need to add `print(dossiersdb)` because without it, there is no exception here but again in the index.html

What is the proper way to catch this exception?

Comment: `Person.objects.using('dbn').all()` is just a query, not the execution. The execution is done when you access to data, for example: `list( Person.objects.using('dbn').all() )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `list()` to force the queryset to be evaluated.

```
try:
  dossiersdb = list(Person.objects.using('dbn').all())
except OperationalError as exp :
  logger.warning("Got %s", exp) 
  return HttpResponse('<h1>OperationalError</h1>')
```

Comment: If I use `list()` does the `dossierdb` queryset will be evaluate two times ? One here in your code and also in the view ?

Comment: No, iterating through the list in the template won't cause the queryset to be evaluated again.

Answer (score 0):

What about a global exception hook?

```
def exception_hook(exctype, value, trace):
    # some exception handling logic here.
    sys.__excepthook__(exctype, value, trace)
sys.excepthook = exception_hook
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to return the error response to the user if you use a global exception hook.